# How to iterate through this json api?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this json api: https://api.glive.live/h5/v1/live_room/home?&page_size=1000

How do I print all "anchor_id"'s ?

```
import requests
api = "https://api.glive.live/h5/v1/live_room/home?"
url = api + '&page_size=1000'
raw_json_data = requests.get(url).json()
data = raw_json_data['rooms']['anchor_id']
print(data)
```

This gives me output:

```
data = raw_json_data['rooms']['anchor_id']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I then try to do:

```
data = raw_json_data['rooms'](str['anchor_id'])
```

And get output:

```
data = raw_json_data['rooms'](str['anchor_id'])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `raw_json_data['rooms']` returns a list of dictionaries, and indexing into a list with a string (`['anchor_id']`) does not make any sense as the original error suggests.

The way you tried to solve it (`raw_json_data['rooms'](str['anchor_id'])`) does not make any sense due to many reasons,  the most obvious one is the fact that `str` is a type, hence `str[...]` is a `TypeError`.

Since `raw_json_data['rooms']` returns a list, you have to  iterate over it with a loop:

```
for room in raw_json_data['rooms']:
    print(room['anchor_id'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
With your solution I only get an output of 10 anchor_id's while the api currently shows 51 ?

Comment: @aquatic7 Where do you see 51? Opening the JSON in the browser and searching for 'anchor_id' finds 10, just like the code above

Comment: Hmmm right now I get 41 on the api but only 10 in the code.

Comment: I found the issue. I had it set as &page_size=1000 where it should be just &size=1000